# Java: How to change Double 2.3 to "2.0"?

Tags: java, floating-point, double

How can I change a

```
Double d = 2.3
```

to

```
Double with value of 2.0
```

I used `Math.round`, but it produces `2.0`

I need to save it to a `String` as `2.0`

Comment: Huh?  What is the difference between 2.0 and 2.0?

Comment: I need to change it to exact `String` representation

Comment: @daydreamer You should probably have mentioned that it needed to be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf(...)`:

```
System.out.printf("Double with value of %.1f", Math.round(d));
```

or you can save it to a String using `String.format(...)`:

```
String s = String.format("Double with value of %1f", Math.round(d));
```

Comment: Hi @Hunter, How can I save this to a `String` variable?

Comment: @daydreamer See updated post, in the future it would be wise to include what you are trying to achieve in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change a numerical value to a string you use:

```
String.valueOf(myDouble);
```

You could also use this if you were using the **Double** wrapper to store your double value:

```
myDouble.toString();
```

So you would use this in conjunction with your Math.round() call.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Hunter, I was able to do that with following

```
 String.valueOf(new Double(Math.round(new Double(Double.parseDouble(minorVersion) + 1.0))));
```

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(..)` already returns a new Double object, there is no need to wrap it with `new Double(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest code:

```
String s = "" + myDouble;
```

Answer (score 0):

The base answer to your question is use

```
String.valueOf(doubleNo) //in your case doubleNo is 2.0 after rounding
```

However, consider using BigDecimal than using double, in which case you can use the following method

```
public String roundAndPrintDouble(double no){
    String numberAsString = String.valueOf(no);
    BigDecimal decimalNo = new BigDecimal(numberAsString);
    BigDecimal roundedDecimal = decimalNo.round(MathContext.DECIMAL128);
    return roundedDecimal.toPlainString();
}
```

If the unlikely case that you do go with this solution, have a look at the JavaDocs for [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) and [MathContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/MathContext.html) before.